# Why sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe & on Mac OS X 10.6.8 doesn't ask for password?

Tags: permissions, osx, sudo, password, mysql

I get the following permissions from terminal:

```
$ cd /usr/local/mysql  
$ ls -l  
drwxr-xr-x  41 root    wheel  1394 29 Apr 00:55 bin  
drwxr-xr-x   4 root    wheel   136 29 Apr 00:55 docs  
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    wheel   102 29 Apr 00:55 include   
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    wheel   102 29 Apr 00:55 lib  
drwxr-xr-x   4 root    wheel   136 29 Apr 00:55 libexec  
drwxr-xr-x  15 root    wheel   510 29 Apr 00:55 mysql-test   
drwxr-xr-x   5 root    wheel   170 29 Apr 00:55 share  
drwxr-xr-x  29 root    wheel   986 29 Apr 00:55 sql-bench  
drwxrwxr-x   3 _mysql  wheel   102  5 Mag 10:56 tmp  
drwxrwxr-x  16 _mysql  wheel   544  5 Mag 10:56 var
```

(mysqld_safe itself has 755). tmp is where mysql.sock resides, var contains the databases. MySQL starts normally with sudo, as specified in the question, but without asking for root password, even after a boot. If mysqld_safe is issued without sudo it obviously fails and complains (permission denied on file in ./var). sudoers file contains just the line below regarding permissions:

```
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 1):

Your rule doesn't specify `NOPASSWD` so it should require a password (`PASSWD`). Have you checked to see if `sudo` is just remembering the last time you entered root's password? By default (unless you set `Default timestamp_timeout=0`) it will do that.

Comment: After further search I found this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/623581/after-rebooting-why-doesnt-sudo-prompt-for-password-when-i-try-to-start-mysql) on superuser. Because of my lack of experience, I didn't noticed the actual behavior which is better described by the link above (i.e. after some test the problems coincide, and on two different OS). I add that if `sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe &` is entered after reboot and before any other `sudo` in a fresh terminal window, sudo process doesn't ask for passw, as said, and moreover it hangs with CPU 100% (at least on my machine).